# encrypt laravel, decrypt react native error

Tags: laravel, react-native

```js
//encrypt di laravel
$data = 'hello world';
$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8');
$encryptedData = Crypt::encryptString($data);

//decrypt di react

const keylah ="test_saja"
const encrypted = JSON.parse(decode (json.data));
// const decryptedData = AES.decrypt(json.data, key);
console.log("encrypted",encrypted);
const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted.iv);
console.log("iv",iv);
const value = encrypted.value;
console.log("value",value);
const key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(keylah);
console.log("key",key);
try {
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(value, key, {
        iv: iv
    });
    console.log("decrypted",decrypted);
    const cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
        ciphertext: CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(new Int32Array(decrypted.words), decrypted.sigBytes),
      });
    const decryptedString = cipherParams.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    console.log("decryptedString",decryptedString);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

output :

```json
{
  "sigBytes": 17,
  "words": \[
    -1633995332,
    1118422985,
    -1080711443,
    -1078091853,
    -871477851,
    -977914936,
    -185412272,
    425789967\
  ]
}
```

if tostring, there is no data

output decrypt value must be : 'hello world';

Answer (score 0):

After decrypting the data in with cryptoJs dont use the cipherparams directly use the convert the data to string, this worked for me

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
export const encryptData = (passCode, data) => {
//salt provides a large set of keys for any given password
let salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8); //Salts are used in 
cryptographic hashing in order to eliminate the possibility of success using 
rainbow table method of cracking.
//PBKDF2 is a password-based key derivation function
let key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(passCode, salt, {
  keySize: 512 / 32,
  iterations: 1000, //iteration count increases the cost of producing keys from 
  a password
});
let iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8); //initialization vector (IV) is 
 an arbitrary number that can be used with a secret key for data encryption to 
 foil cyber attacks. Its also called as nonce
let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key, {
   iv: iv,
   padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
  //Padding describe which values should be appended to the message, to fill up 
  the last block. Using padding is a convenient way of making sure that 
  encrypted data is of the correct size.
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
});
let ciphertext = encrypted.toString();
return {ciphertext,key,iv};
};

export const decryptData = (encrypted, data) => {
//for decrypting both IV and Key is needed to decrypt the file
let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, data.key, {
  iv: data.iv,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
});
return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
};
```